Why is 网 considered inside the 亡 phonetic series on wikitionary?
On wikitionary's page about phonetic series under the 亡 entry we find 网 even though 网 is described to be a pictogram on it's own wikitionary page.
If we look on wikipedia's page about Phonetic series, it says "phonological series is a set of Chinese characters sharing the same sound-based element". I would expect this means the character needs to have the sound-based element as it's component.
Is this a mistake or is there another reason they are consider part of the same phonetic series?

Ah I'm silly, 网 the radical probably isn't part of the phonetic series, only 网 the character, which in traditional was 網 which contains 亡

I was about to type a comment indicating the same thing. If the title where Wiktionary got the phonetic series from (Zhengzhang, Shangfang (鄭張尚芳) (2003). 上古音系 (Old Chinese Phonology)) uses 網 instead of 网, then 网 is just a duplicate entry.

「网」 is listed under the phonetic series of 「亡」, because the word which 「网」 represented (Zhengzhang OC: /*mlaŋʔ/, hunting and fishing net) was written with at least 3 different variants (网、罔、網), and the latter two in this list of 3 include 「亡」 (/*maŋ/) as a phonetic component.

Wiktionary's phonetic series comes from Zhèngzhāng Shàngfāng's Old Chinese Phonology (2003) (鄭張尚芳《上古音系》). In this title, the phonetic series for 「亡」 is listed under Heading W (for pinyin Wáng) in Appendix IV (page 484):

喪　心唐 c1 開蘇浪　亡陽　　smaaŋs　說文从亡亡亦聲，甲文借桑字，金文始加亡
...
亡　微陽 a3 合武方　亡陽　　maŋ
...
网　微陽 b3 合文兩　亡陽　　mlaŋʔ
罔　微陽 b3 合文兩　亡陽　　mlaŋʔ　亦同網
...
網　微陽 b3 合文兩　亡陽　　mlaŋʔ　同网

The word /*mlaŋʔ/ (hunting and fishing net) is listed three times (网、罔、網) in this phonetic series, reflecting the complexification that this character went through over time:



時期字體
字形丨隸定
參考資料




商甲

甲3112合集10514


商甲

庫653合集40757


戰國・楚簡

56.31九店竹簡


秦簡

秦5睡虎地秦簡


東漢隸

論語・爲政熹平石經



Here, the character was originally a picture of a net, written variously as 「冈」, 「网」, or similar. Possibly due to confusion with other similar shapes such as 「五」, a phonetic 「亾・亡」 (/*maŋ/) was added later on, forming 「罔」.
「網」 (not shown) is a much later complexification via addition of semantic 「糸」 (threads, indicating the manufacturing material for the net), after 「罔」 came to taken on a phonetic loan role (to not have; to deceive).

It is not a mistake, 亡 and 网 are same in  sound, only in differently 声调.

或许可能是 网 和 亡 的声母韵母都是wang，所以把他们放到一起了。
